can you use Lists calculated column to calculate dates ignoring specific days, (eg. not counting saturday, sunday.)
Aloha, i am trying to create a calculated column that takes a [start date] and calculate 30 business days forward ignoring saturday and sunday as [expiration date]
eg:
[start date] - [expiration date]
5/7/2024        6/18/2024
any help greatly appreciated!
